# How do I get EKS GPU AMIs with Nvidia driver version >=440 (for CUDA 10.2)?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-ami, amazon-eks, nvidia-docker

We have been using CUDA 10.2 for our machine learning tasks and AWS EKS AMIs don't have Nvidia drivers that support CUDA 10.2 (driver version >=440).

Where should I get the required images?

Comment: Does [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/gpu-ami.html) solve your problem?

Comment: No, I looked into it a bit I couldn't find a proper solution.